# Setting an image as a background of <div> without pixels

Tags: html, css

I need to set an image as a background of div but i haven't founded a way how to do it without setting the exact height of div in pixels. I want the div to be always the size of the picture and when resolution is smaller to adjust the resolution. I don't want to do it by pixels and @media, there must be a simplier way.

html

```
<div class="foo">
</div>
```

css

```
.foo{
height: "exact height of picture of bg";   !!!
background: url("./foo/bar.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat black;
}
```

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - Solution using JS to get image size
This will get the image size, with this you can then use JS to set the width and height of the area you want to display the image
I have commented the code to explain what is going on

```
'use strict';

// wait for the document to be ready then run our task
// we're outputting to a div so need to wait for div to be available
window.onload = runTask();

function runTask() {
    // get the div that you want to output to
    const output = document.getElementById('output');

  // image to measure, example using a wikimedia image
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/JavaScript-logo.png/768px-JavaScript-logo.png';

  // output image dimensions, again have to wait for image to load
  // thanks to David Walsh blog for this info
  // https://davidwalsh.name/get-image-dimensions
  image.onload = function() {
    output.innerHTML = "Image width: " + image.naturalWidth + "<br />Image Height: " + image.naturalHeight;
  };
};
```

To view this code working - https://jsfiddle.net/2L521dk5/27/

ORIGINAL

Are you open to using JavaScript? You could detect the images size and scale the div accordingly
Also, does it have to be a background image?

Comment: The thing is that it needs to be owerflew by text and other stuff, so yes, i dont want to use z-index as well, that wouldn't solve my problem. I am a begginer in JS :/

Comment: I'll be in the office in a bit and will post a js solution for you. Also, positioning and z-index would be a good flexible solution

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="yourpicture.jpg"/>
```

Thats it.

Comment: Heh, it needs to be owerflew by text and other stuff, thats the point why i need it as a background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the background image responsive when your div is resized the best way to do that is to set the background-size of the div to:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

That way you can still put content over the `<div>` background image like you are trying to do. You couldn't do that with an `<img>` element

Comment: Yeah, but i need the background to be always full. I can use img tag, but i need to put a text over it, so i need to do it as a bg.

Comment: If you need the picture to fill the div, the background-size property should be set to 100% 100%.

Comment: This will distort the image, as it will lose its aspect ratio. Better to use background-size: cover in this case. It won't cover the whole div though. Or increase the size by using background-size: 150% auto

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "" for url on CSS.

```css
.foo {
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/27060/images/example.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
text<br>text<br>text
</div>
```